# how to use a user input defined in one html page in another php page to fetch data from oracle database

Tags: php, post

I have one php page which connects to the oracle database and fetches some data based on some user input. Here in this case Once the user will enter the user_id, and submit it, my code will fetch some more data (REQUEST_TIME,WORKFLOW_NAME,EVENT_MESSAGE) of that user. I am running below code and i am not sure if i am doing it correct. I am getting below error:

**Warning:  oci_execute(): ORA-00904: "USER_ID": invalid identifier in D:\SVN\TOOLBOX_WEB\WEBContent\admin\V2\public\ssn\index2.php on line 36**

can someone please guide, how to proceed.

This is my php page:

```
<pre><?php

include('mypage.php');
class logAgent
{
    const CONFIG_FILENAME = "data_config.ini";

    private $_dbConn;
    private $_config;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->_loadConfig();


        $this->_dbConn = oci_connect($this->_config['db_usrnm'],
            $this->_config['db_pwd'],
            $this->_config['hostnm_sid']);
    }
    private function _loadConfig()
    {
        // Loads config
        $path = dirname(__FILE__) . '/' . self::CONFIG_FILENAME;
        $this->_config = parse_ini_file($path) ;
    }
    public function fetchLogs() {
        $uid =$_POST["USER_ID"];

        $sql = "SELECT REQUEST_TIME,WORKFLOW_NAME,EVENT_MESSAGE
                            FROM AUTH_LOGS WHERE USER_ID = '".$uid."'";

        //Preparing an Oracle statement for execution
        $statement = oci_parse($this->_dbConn, $sql);

        //Executing statement
        oci_execute($statement);
        while (($row = oci_fetch_row($statement)) != false) {
            foreach ($row as $item) {
                echo $item . " ";
            }
            echo "\n";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

mypage.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>User_Logs</title>
    </head>

    <body>
 <?php
  if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
   $uid =$_POST["USER_ID"];
   $logAgent = new logAgent();
   $logAgent->fetchLogs();
  }
  ?>
        <form method="POST" id="form-add" action="index2.php">
   USER_ID: <input type="text" name="USER_ID"/><br>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Get_Logs"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your error, oracle is complaining that it can't find the field USER_ID.  Looking at your SELECT statement in the php file, oracle expects that field to be in your AUTH_LOGS table.  Check to ensure that you've spelt the name of the field correctly or that the field exists in the table.